# What does the symbol $\mathbb{I}$ mean? as in, $\Bbb{I}_{\{U(0,1)<p\}}$

Tags: statistics, notation

I encountered this symbol $\mathbb{I}$ in the following text. What does it represent? I can't make sense of this equation.

[image]

Comment: I would guess an indicator function; i.e. $$\mathbb I_A(\omega) := \begin{cases} 1 & \omega \in A \\ 0 & \omega\notin A\end{cases}$$

Comment: It is a fancy numeral 1 or letter I, used for an indicator function = characteristic function.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I see, thanks!, I think that makes sense in the context of the following paragraph where it says that $p$ determines the frequency of noise disturbance. The ratio of the two normal distributed random variables would be the noise then.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks! it makes sense now